# Creating simple pure Javascript slider on swipe for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create something similar to Google slider for images on searching on small screen sizes, Just make the browser width smaller or visit it from mobile, Then type 'image' in Google search box for example, You will see 3 images beneath Google search box that you can slide to show more images.

So there will be about 6 images next to each other, But 2 are fully shown and about half of the 3rd image, While the 3 others will be hidden.

As the user swipe to the left the 3rd image and the other 3 would become visible, The user should still can swipe to the right to show the first images if he already swiped to the left.

I tried to analyze the one on Google, But there are elements those I see for the first time, And I don't know how to find the related JS functions, If this is done with pure JS.

That's what I tried so far:

```
var ImageIndex = 0;

function swipe(event){
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    var midpoint = Math.floor(screen.width/2);
    var px = touch.pageX;
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('image-wrapper');
    var itemActive = items[ImageIndex]; 
    if(px < midpoint){
        itemActive.style.marginLeft = '-100%';
        itemActive.style.transition = '1s';
        if (ImageIndex < items.length) {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex + 1;
        }else{
            ImageIndex = 0;
        }
    }else{
        itemActive.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        itemActive.style.transition = '1s';
        if (ImageIndex >= 1 ) {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex - 1;
        }else{
            ImageIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.images-gallary{
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 73px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.image-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#secondItem{
    background: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="images-gallary" ontouchmove="swipe(event)">
    <div class="image-wrapper" id="firstItem">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/73/200">
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper" id="secondItem">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/73/300">
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/73/400">
    </div>
</div> <!-- .images-gallary -->
```

This code just slide the first 2 images, And I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

So how to customize that code to work as mentioned at the top?

I don't want to use Jquery or any libraries, Just pure JS code.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem in your case is in this condition `if (ImageIndex < items.length) {`. You have total amount of 3 elements, therefore when `ImageIndex` is 2, it will increment it to `3` and as you have 3 images in the html `items[ImageIndex]` will return undefined.

So change the condition to `if (ImageIndex < items.length - 1) {`.

Comment: You are right that fixed the error, But how to implement the 2 and half images idea?

Comment: What should be a desired behavior, when in the initial state the user swipes left. It should move to the second image or the third one?

Comment: There are 6 images right now, I want 1 of the 2 following cases:
1- 2 images are fully displayed and part of the 3rd image and the last 3 images are hidden, When the user swipes left the hidden parts of the 3rd image would be shown and as swiping the other 3 images would be shown too, And for sure if the user swiped to the left he could swipe to the right again

Comment: Case 2: 3 images/1 image are/is shown and the user can swipe to show the 3 others as he is swiping.

Comment: One more thing, When I swipe the images to the left, The 3 images containers take `margin-left: -100%`, So when I swipe the first image only the 3 images are moved to out of the screen and only the main container `images-gallary` is visible

Comment: so you need to only add margin not 100%, but a smaller values based on the selected image, something like that `(imageIndex + 1) * (100 / 6)` (6 is total amount of images). So you won't move the container to the end, but rather to the next image.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first condition `ImageIndex < items.length` with `ImageIndex < (items.length - 1)`    because total images length is 3 here and trying to access style of `items[3]` (`undefined`)

```
if (ImageIndex < (items.length - 1)) {
   ImageIndex = ImageIndex + 1;
}else {
   ImageIndex = 0;
}
```

and one more thing in 2nd condition you should have replace `ImageIndex = 0;` with  `ImageIndex = items.length - 1;` in else condition because always initialising same value `ImageIndex = 0;` in case of `px > midpoint`  and `ImageIndex < 1`

```
if (ImageIndex >= 1 ) {
   ImageIndex = ImageIndex - 1;
}else {
   ImageIndex = items.length-1;
}
```

your final code seems like below:

```
var ImageIndex = 0;

function swipe(event){
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    var midpoint = Math.floor(screen.width/2);
    var px = touch.pageX;
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('image-wrapper');
    var itemActive = items[ImageIndex]; 
    if(px < midpoint){
        itemActive.style.marginLeft = '-100%';
        itemActive.style.transition = '1s';
        if (ImageIndex < (items.length - 1)) {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex + 1;
        }else{
            ImageIndex = 0;
        }
    }else{
        itemActive.style.marginLeft = '0px';
        itemActive.style.transition = '1s';
        if (ImageIndex >= 1 ) {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex - 1;
        }else{
            ImageIndex = items.length - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I updated it, Do you have method  to implement the idea in at the top of the question?

Comment: One more thing, When I swipe the images to the left, The 3 images containers take `margin-left: -100%`, So when I swipe the first image only the 3 images are moved to out of the screen and only the main container `images-gallary` is visible

Comment: for 2nd you can give default css to all images and at a time one image should be active, others will take default css like use ```translate``` to in big amount. active image will be visible.

Comment: I want to always show 3 images of 6, The user can swipe to the left and right to show one and hide another per time

Comment: @maxwell initially all 3 images should have active and all others should default css. Add and remove class according to your swipe left or right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183457/discussion-between-jaisa-ram-and-maxwell).